# Run task in background using deferredResult in Spring without frozen browser as client

Tags: spring, multithreading, blocking, nonblocking, deferred

I have implemented a simple `Rest service` by which I'd like to test `deferredResult` from `Spring`. While am I getting texts in that order:

1. TEST
2. TEST 1
3. TEST AFTER DEFERRED RESULT

I am very interested why in a browser (client) I need to wait that 8 seconds. Isn't that `deferedResult` shouldn't be non-blocking and run a task in the background? If no, how to create a rest service which will be non-blocking and run tasks in the background without using `Java 9` and reactive streams?

```
@RestController("/")
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping
    public DeferredResult<Person> test() {
        System.out.println("TEST");
        DeferredResult<Person> result = new DeferredResult<>();
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::test1)
                .whenCompleteAsync((res, throwable) -> {
                    System.out.println("TEST AFTER DEFERRED RESULT");
                    result.setResult(res);
                });
        System.out.println("TEST 1");
        return result;
    }

    private Person test1() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(8000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new Person("michal", 20);
    }
}

class Person implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`DeferredResult` is a holder for a `WebRequest` to allow the serving thread to release and serve another incoming HTTP request instead of waiting for the current one's result. After `setResult` or `setError` methods will be invoked - Spring will release that stored `WebRequest` and your client will receive the response.

 
`DeferredResult` holder is a Spring Framework abstraction for Non-blocking IO threading.
Deferred result abstraction has nothing with background tasks. Calling it without threading abstractions will cause the expected same thread execution. Your `test1` method is running in the background because of `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` method invocation that gives the execution to common pool.
The result is returned in 8 seconds because the `whenCompleteAsync` passed callback will be called only after `test1` method will return.

You cannot receive the result immediately when your "service call logic" takes 8 seconds despite you are performing it in the background. If you want to release the HTTP request - just return an available proper object (it could contain a UUID, for example, to fetch the created person later) or nothing from the controller method. You can try to `GET` your created user after **N** seconds. There are specific HTTP response codes (202 ACCEPTED), that means the serverside is processing the request. Finally just *GET* your created object.

The second approach (if you should notify your clientside - but I will not recommend you to do it if this is the only reason) - you can use WebSockets to notify the clientside and message with it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So what are others way to accomplish to run task in the background- so in that case means that client will return value immediately and ex test1 method will continue running?

Comment: I updated the answer, but Reactive Programming will not help you in this case. The TCP connection should be open despite the used stack with HTTP.

Comment: Thanks. So can you tell me what is the main difference between deferred result and @async annotation in spring?

Comment: `@Async` annotations just provide a declarative way to specify methods we as developers want to run in the background (another TreadPoolExecutor).  It makes your methods run in the background instead of the `DeferredResult`. DeferredResult was implemented to make the threading IO more non-blocking (to allow one thread serve multiple requests) and is more coupled with MVC. Here is also a good explanation of the difference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855852/difference-between-spring-mvcs-async-deferredresult-and-callable